# How to change selected radio box with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is the part of the code for radio box

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div>
              <label ng-click="setGroup(true)">
                <input type="radio" id="groupNamId" name="quality[21]" checked="checked"  ng-value="isGroupName" /> Group Name
              </label>
              <label ng-click="setGroup(false)">
                <input type="radio" id="Distinguished1" name="quality[21]"  ng-value="!isGroupName"  /> DN Name 
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Now the radio box is checked on "Group Name" but I want the radio box is checked   on either Group Name or DN Name basing on the isGroupName. So if isGroupName = true then Group Name radio box is checked and if isGroupName=false then DN Name   radio box is checked. Any suggestion for changing the radio checked on   isGroupName? I have use ng-checked but it didn't work.
Thanks,
Kim

Comment: You cannot check two radio buttons anyhow with the same name. Use checkbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should us [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to manage your [radio with angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) properly.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div>
      <label ng-click="setGroup(true)">
        <input type="radio" id="groupNamId" name="quality[21]" ng-model="isGroupName" value="Group" /> Group Name
      </label>
      <label ng-click="setGroup(false)">
        <input type="radio" id="Distinguished1" name="quality[21]"  ng-model="isGroupName" value="DN"  /> DN Name 
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller :

```
<script>
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.isGroupName = "DN";
    }]);
</script>
```

With ng-model, no need to a boolean isGroupName ... Angular will automaticaly ind proper value based on your data. No error possible like forgetting keep your boolean sync.

This Plunker explain well how it works : http://plnkr.co/edit/vjryMq3SbJEdhSjiqZ9U?p=preview